# Fontawsome icon not working in bootstrap table item . Why?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, html-table

I am using Fontawsome free v 5.15.4, and bootstrap 5.1. I am creating a table with js.

```
let newBtn = createAnyElement("button", {
        class: "btn btn-success",
        onclick: "createUser(this)"
    });
    newBtn.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>`;
    tr.appendChild(newBtn);

    return tr;
```

With this code, the  green button works fine: [image: works]

But when I do the following:

```
let newBtn = createAnyElement("button", {
        class: "btn btn-success",
        onclick: "createUser(this)"
    });
    newBtn.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>`;
    let td = createAnyElement("td");
    td.appendChild(newBtn);
    tr.appendChild(td);

    return tr;
```

The button disapears. It only shows on hover. [image: Only on hover]
I can't seam to figure out why?

( createAnyElement function is as follows:

```
function createAnyElement(name, attributes) {
    let element = document.createElement(name);
    for (let k in attributes) {
        element.setAttribute(k, attributes[k]);
    }
    return element;
}
```

)

Also for clarification, the whole function is as follows:

```
function newUserRow(row) {
    let tr = createAnyElement("tr");
    for(let k in {id: '', name: '', email: ''}) {
        let td = createAnyElement("td");
        let input = createAnyElement("input", {
            class: "form-control",
            name: k
        });
        td.appendChild(input);
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }

    let newBtn = createAnyElement("button", {
        class: "btn btn-success",
        onclick: "createUser(this)"
    });
    newBtn.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>`;
    let td = createAnyElement("td");
    td.appendChild(newBtn);
    tr.appendChild(td);

    return tr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
let newRow = newUserRow();
    table.appendChild(newRow);
```

to

```
let newRow = newUserRow();
    tbody.appendChild(newRow);
```

It is now working.